# How can I interpret this MATLAB code for LU decomposition using Doolittle's Method?

Tags: matlab

I am seeking an interpretation of this code, line-by-line. It basically decomposes a square matrix into a lower (L) and upper (U) triangular matrix using Doolittle's Method. The source where I found this didn't have any explanations.

```
A=H;
[m,n]=size(A); 
U=zeros(m);
L=zeros(m);
for j=1:m
    L(j,j)=1;
end
for j=1:m
    U(1,j)=A(1,j);
end
for i=2:m
    for j=1:m
        for k=1:i-1
            s1=0;
            if k==1
                s1=0;
            else
            for p=1:k-1
                s1=s1+L(i,p)*U(p,k);
            end
            end
            L(i,k)=(A(i,k)-s1)/U(k,k);
           end
         for k=i:m
             s2=0;
           for p=1:i-1
               s2=s2+L(i,p)*U(p,k);
           end
           U(i,k)=A(i,k)-s2;
         end
    end
end
disp('The Lower Triangular Matrix using the Doolittle Method is')
L
disp('The Upper Triangular Matrix using the Doolittle Method is')
U
```

Comment: You can only understand it if you understand the method, and once you understand the method then there is little to explain (I think). Unfortunately this is not a place to get math lectures, that you need to do on your own.

Comment: @AnderBiguri would it be possible to help me understand the method?

Comment: " Unfortunately this is not a place to get math lectures, that you need to do on your own."